# I need to create a flat file from database table with fixed field length

Tags: c#

The export needs to be fixed length file that means each field will have predefined location and length like below:

```
Field A: 20 char

Field B: 15 char

Field C: 10 char
```

For following values:

```
Field A                 Field B                  Field C
Test 1                  Test 2                   Test 3
This is value 1         This is value 2          This is va
```

Flat file contents should be:

```
Test 1              Test 2         Test 3    
This is value 1     This is value 2This is va
```

like Test 1 field have all 20 character including space up to the field Test 2 and same as Test 2 field have 15 character up to field Test 3 and Test 3 field also have 15 character up to end including spaces.

please tell me solution for this either i want to generate it from sql server database table or by c# coding  any way.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please post your code. Also see : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: When? Why? Where? There are dozens of possible ways to do that, from an integration services to a custom C# application. Powershell may also be very simple to use

Answer (score 1):

This code shows how to do it:

```
// 1 reading data from database
var data = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    data.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(i.ToString(), (i + 1).ToString(), (i * 3000).ToString()));
}

// 2 writing data to file
foreach (var record in data)
{
    var str = string.Format("{0,-20}{1,-15}{2,-10}", record.Item1, record.Item2, record.Item3);

    Console.WriteLine(str); // <- or file.WriteLine(...)
}
```

Since I have no idea what are your model (or domain) objects, I have used a simple `Tuple<string, string, string>` instead.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Use a CSV library! (Ex: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper).

Comment: Thanks @SteveB for mentioning that. But the last time I saw that library (I think more than a year ago, I hope I am not mistaken) it had not support for fixed width columns. Is it changed now?

Comment: @SteveB And if it does support fixed width columns, please post this as an answer. It would be a help for others and it's your answer anyway! :)

Comment: Not sure it supports fixed length. However, my purpose was not to promote this library specifically, but more to looks for a ready to use, mature, CSV library to avoid common mistakes (string escaping for example)

Comment: @SteveB (This needs a long discussion I think.) I do use "the wheel" very much: NLog, Ninject, AutoMapper, etc; but I think YAGNI! I mean as far as this code works and there is no obvious point of extensibility; I use this code. A practice I follow is I always write a code and "USE" it before make it "REUSABLE": premature optimization. Now do I really need to add another library to my project (administration, adoption, learning curve, deployment, maintenance, etc)? How much actual value it adds to my work?

Comment: all situations are different, of course. We all just have to choose knowing the possibilities... not just following the first obvious path.